# When is the degree $(2,2)$ motivic cohomology generated by products of units?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology

The motivic coniveau spectral sequence tells us that for a scheme $X/k$, its cohomology $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}(2))$ is the kernel of the tame symbol $K_2^M(k(X))\to \oplus_{Y} K_1^M(k(Y))$ where $Y$ runs over all divisors in $X$. Thus, all elements of this motivic cohomology group can be generated by linear combinations products of elements in $k(X)^\times$, such that their tame symbols cancel out.

**Question**: when is it the case that elements in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}(2))$ can all be generated by products of actual units on $X$?

Cases where this is known and specific illustrative counterexamples are both welcome. Results ignoring torsion are of use as well. If anything is known for bidegree-$(k,k)$, that would also be interesting.

Comment: How will you cancel residues if you do not allow at least two pure tensors (with opposite signs)?

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something; where am I not allowing multiple pure tensors?

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  I thought that you were asking about “symbol length”.  I now see that you are asking about whether you can choose the units in $k(X)^\times$ to be elements in $\mathcal{O}_X(X)^\times$.

Comment: That should be the case if $X$ is a product of copies of the multiplicative group.

Comment: Can anything be said for curves in general?